# How to return a value from .filter instead of the element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
function firstDuplicate(a) {
  const duplicates = a.filter((el,idx) => {
    let myVar = a.indexOf(el,idx+1);
    console.log(myVar); // returns 4
    if (myVar >= 0) return myVar; // duplicates becomes [1] instead of [4]
  });
  console.log('duplicates are',duplicates);
}
const myArr = [1,2,3,4,1];
```

I'm trying to return a value from filter instead of the array element. How do I do this? Ultimately I want to get all the duplicates in an array for a coding challenge.

Comment: if you want to return a value other than a boolean i.e. `true` or `false` then use the `map` method not `filter`

Comment: You can't, that's not what `filter` is for, it's the wrong method for your task. `map` is what you're after.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :) I'm also interested in using Set, but don't think it's suitable for this because it automatically removes unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter` method should be used to do what the name states, *filter elements*, i.e. retain elements that pass the provided predicate and discard those elements where the predicate returns false.

In this particular case, you're after the `map` operation as you want to *transform* elements rather than *filter*.